# Android Studio Translations Editor with Flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I have a whitelabel app meaning I have a "main" part of a code and then from that create "reskins" which in the project are represented by flavors.

I have string values which are shared across all flavors but some differ from flavor to flavor, i.e. the app name

I'm trying to simplify my work and use the Translations Editor in Android Studio but the thing doesn't seem to work properly. I enter a translation and it inserts the changes in the wrong files. I though that my changing Build variants, it'll only show me the strings from the "common" strings.xml and the strings.xml from the current variant, but no, it seems it shows me the first translation it finds for a string and does not limit itself to the current flavor folder.

How can I use Translation Editor to force it to set the translations and limit itself to only one build variant (one flavor folder) and not ruining the translations in my other flavors.